# RXJS combineLatest how to fire individually and together

Tags: rxjs

As an example I've built out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yupdon/m2rvqn9t/)  (updated with answer)

I love what its doing but what I'd like it to do is fire if I only type in input1 and just give me "empty" results for 2 and 3.

Is something like this possible? ( in the example provided all inputs must have a value)

```
var obs1 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input1, 'input').map((e) => e.target.value);
var obs2 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input2, 'input').map((e) => e.target.value);
var obs3 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input3, 'input').map((e) => e.target.value);

var counter = 0;

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(obs1, obs2, obs3)           
        .subscribe(([ res1, res2, res3 ]) => {
  span.textContent = 'Result: ' + ++counter + ' -> ' + res1 +
                    ' / ' +
                    res2 +
                    ' / ' +
                    res3;
        });
```

Comment: If you use `obs1.withLatestFrom(obs2, obs3)` is it doing what you want?

Comment: I would have to implement that for obs1.with.... and obs2.with.... and obs3.with.... to get them all to fire individually and or together, not to mention all variations.

Comment: Then you can just use `startWith` for `obs2` and `obs3`. Like `combineLatest(obs1, obs2.startWith(undefined), obs3.startWith(undefined)) `

Comment: interesting! i'll give it a go in a few

Comment: @martin That worked, if you want to make an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `startWith` operator for `obs2` and `obs3`:

```
combineLatest(
  obs1.startWith(undefined),
  obs2.startWith(undefined),
  obs3.startWith(undefined)
).pipe(skip(1)) //skip the initial undefined result set
.subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => { ... })
```

Comment: Never thought to do it this way, but I like it! With the pipe, it's a little less concise now but works well!